# Please explain this equation

Tags: transformer

[image]
I am reading about maximum efficiency of transformers.I am not able to get the second step.please explain...

Comment: Subtract R_s, multiply by -I_s^2.

Comment: This is basic algebra, you should probably strengthen your knowledge in that field before tackling more difficult topics.

Comment: Basic Ohm's Law.  Anything with resistance causes heat loss with square law on current,  P=I²R  unlike pure reactance (L,C) which just stored energy.  P is the correct  symbol for power while [W] is the units in Watts.

Comment: OK, this equation looks like an equation. Be specific please

Answer (score 2):

This is basic maths.

$$ - \frac {W_i}{I^2_S} + \bar R_S = 0 $$

Multiply across by \$ I^2_S \$.

$$ -  {W_i} + {I^2_S} \bar R_S = 0 $$

Add \$ W_i \$ to both sides.

$${I^2_S} \bar R_S = {W_i} $$

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed basic maths. 
I hope this one can help.

[image]

Comment: Lol! Why did it not click my mind that time